# Rails remote link as a non-inline, non-form "button"

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, button

I'm trying to do an ajax "button" (not an actual form button) that behaves just like a normal `link_to "content", some_path, remote:true` would. And when I click it, it swaps out the image to indicate the status (e.g. on/off, voted/not voted, etc.)

The reason is, I want to use javascript to add class, to swap out images, toggling them. Usually, people do this by specifying the background-image property in CSS for a given class, and add/remove classes via javascript.

But of course, if you use the rails link_to, that creates an a tag, which is an inline element. This inline element is not friendly for the desired above mentioned behavior. You end up having to use an actual image tag, making the javascript DOM traversal, as well as the CSS messier. You also end up doing silly stuff like

```
<div>
  <a>
    <div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

just to keep the link tag as an `a` tag, while trying to ensure a certain size of the "button"

I am looking for an elegant way to accomplish creating a simple ajax "button" that behaves just like a remote link, where it's not a form button, and where I can simply add/remove a class to the element in order to swap out images via CSS.

Is there a good solution to this? Or will I have to use spaghetti jquery and ajax calls on a div element with a specified size? (I've tried nesting a `content_tag` within a `link_to` but that's no better than nesting an `image_tag` in place of the `content_tag`) (I've thought about doing `display: block` to the a tag with `width: 100%`. Is this method any good? why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote option on link_to was created to allow ajax requests to the link URL. As you are querying the server, the change of class should only occur when the AJAX query is successfully completed. I would do it that way:

```
<%= link_to "Vote", some_path, remote:true, "data-type" => :json, class: "vote-button" %>
```

With the following jquery code:

```
$('.vote-button').on('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
  if(data.voted == true){
    $(this).addClass("voted");
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass("voted");
  }
})
```

Assuming your controller action returns a JSON object containing the voted key:

```
class VoteController < ApplicationController
  def update
    voted = # Some stuff happening here that says if voted or not
    render :json => {voted: voted}
  end
end
```

And your css would look like:

```
.vote-button{
  background-image: asset-url(unvoted.png);
}

.vote-button.voted{
  background-image: asset-url(voted.png);
}
```

Don't just copy paste this as I'm not 100% sure it works, but you get the idea.

Comment: I do want it to go to a url. I just want it to also do what you said. Can I just remove `event.preventDefault(); and have it do both?

Comment: It's not enough. As you're querying the server you'd have to make sure the ajax call was successful before toggling the class. Check out my edited answer.

Comment: Oh, so ajax:success makes it trigger after it's successful, whereas before, using `on click` was triggering it before the server loaded? and it would nullify the classes toggled? I'm not sure that attempted explanation quite right.

Comment: Yes, with only the click event you'd have changed the class without knowing if the call was successful. I'm not sure what you mean by nullify the classes toggled but it would have made your UI inconsistent. You want the voted background to show when you're sure it's been voted on and the not-voted background in the other case. A way to do it is by sending back some information from the server giving the status of the vote, as I suggested.

Comment: ohhh you're addressing keeping things in sync with the server side. This was a big concern I didn't know how to address. Thank you so much. What I meant by nullification, was currently, my javascript doesn't update the classes when I click them, but does when I refresh the page. I was guessing maybe the server call somehow "undoes / nullifies" my addClass/removeClass calls.

Comment: In your edited answer, does the json hash passed simply replace the `:json` symbol for "data-type"?  I am trying to set different values for each option in the poll, so I made it an array, but not in json. It was an array of string values, either `"voted"` or `""`, and i looped through them in the view as well. After I pass a json hash or array of multiple values, what would be the syntax to call one of them from a loop of links in the view file? Something like `"data-type" => :json.key => value`?

Comment: No, the data-type attribute is just to tell the remote link it is supposed to ask for a json payload back from the server. If you check the html that rails generates, you'll see that it added a data-remote=true and a data-type=json. It's not an object, just information for jquery_ujs to know what to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59148/discussion-between-marc-lainez-and-gwho).